# Excel VBA Index inside of match function

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

I've got this chunk of code that works when I enter it inside of cell

```
=MATCH(1;INDEX(($B:$B="Some_value1")*($D:$D="Some_value2");0);0)
```

When I "translate" it to VBA code I get typemismatch error.

```
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(1, Application.WorksheetFunction.Index((Range("B:B") = "Some_value1") * (Range("D:D") = "Some_value2"), 0), 0)
```

So can anyone point me where my mistake is or am I even doing it right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In this code Some_value1/2 is string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping in mind that the inner matrix reflects a condition based on worksheet logic (returning an array of 0 or 1 cell values) it seems that you have to execute an evaluation at least within the `INDEX` part:

```
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.Match(1, WorksheetFunction.Index(Evaluate("($B:$B=""Some_value1"")*($D:$D=""Some_value2"")"), 0), 0)
```

or to evaluate the entire expression:

```
Debug.Print Evaluate("=MATCH(1,INDEX(($B:$B=""Some_value1"")*($D:$D=""Some_value2""),0),0)")
```

Comment: Thats solution. Thanks.

Another one, do i have to use variables for range (eg range $B:$B) input, or i can write Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(x,y).Address,Sheet.Cells(z,y).Address) ?

Comment: Also, how do i reference variable (Array of strings (but iterating with for loop) to part ""Some_value""

Comment: ad 1) The expression to be evaluated is a string; so you have to replace the relevant part not by including the range object, but by joining the range **address** `"$B:$B"` as text, e.g. via `Evaluate("(" & Sheet1.columns(2).Address & "=""Some_value1"")*...`

Comment: ad 2) I don't understand exactly what you mean. - Maybe you should pose another question as it seems to deviate from the original issue :-)

Comment: Same thing you answered in ad 1) but for value that im searching.

How ""Some_value"" should be replaced with variable : Search_term ?

I tried with "" & Search_term(i) & "" but it didnt worked

Comment: Nevermind, i figured it out. Just write """ & Search_term(i) & """"

Comment: Glad it worked; so I think you understood the double quotations inside a string and its cumulative appearance.